# Android - DrawerLayout only shows Back Arrow

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to build in a hamburger menu into my Android (Kotlin) application. I thought I followed all of the steps, but only the back arrow show, which does nothing. I can however slide the menu from the left.

I then started a new application and tried to start from scratch, with the same result. Again the statusbar is shown, with only the back arrow.

I'm can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**mainActivity.kt**

```
package com.wensline.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        ///
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code

```kotlin
 setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

To this

```kotlin
 toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I changed the line to ```toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, drawerLayout)``` This solved my issue !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ActionBarDrawerToggle to achieve this -

```
private lateinit var drawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
```

In onCreate method you need to initialize drawerToggle as below -

```
drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true)
toggle.syncState()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for the suggestions. The answer of @KakyireLastBorn give me an idea. I changed the line

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

to

```
 toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, drawerLayout)
```

This solved the issue !